# Does F# have the ternary ?: operator?

Tags: f#, conditional-operator

I'm learning F# coming from C# and I've just tried compiling an expression like

```
let y = Seq.groupBy (fun x -> (x < p ? -1 : x == p ? 0: 1))
```

but see 'unexpected integer literal in expression'. Does F# have a ternary operator? If not, what should I use instead?

Comment: Unrelated, but for this you may just want to use `x.CompareTo(p)` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/43hc6wht(v=vs.110).aspx  That works for most types where `<` and `==` works...

Comment: @Reed Copsey Not totally unrelated for sure, but yes somewhat tangential to my learning objective. :)

Comment: Yes, just unrelated to the ternary capabilities - but much cleaner to write `(fun x -> x.CompareTo(p))` imo :)

Comment: @ReedCopsey In F# you can use the function `compare` so `(fun x -> compare p x)` can also be written as `compare p` but `(fun x -> compare x p)` becomes  `((˜-) >> compare -p)` which is not more readable than the lambda ;)

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Yes, it's called `if .. then .. else`

In fact in F# everything is an expression, even an `if .. then .. else`  block.

In C# `var x = true ? 0 : 1;`

In F# `let x = if true then 0 else 1`

So in your case:

```
let y = Seq.groupBy (fun x -> if x < p then -1 else if x = p then 0 else 1)
```

you can shorten it a bit with `elif`

```
let y = Seq.groupBy (fun x -> if x < p then -1 elif x = p then 0 else 1)
```

Another option to consider in F# specially when you have more than 2 cases is pattern matching:

```
let f p x =
    match x with
    | x when x < p -> -1
    | x when x = p ->  0
    | _ -> 1

let y = Seq.groupBy (f p)
```

But in your particular case I would use the if .. then .. elif .. then.

Finally note that the test-equality operator is `=` not `==` as in C#.

Comment: In the expression `if x < p then -1 elif x = p then 0 else 1` how do we know which "if" the `else` belongs to?

Comment: It correspond to the previous if or elif. It's the same as combining many ? : in C#

Comment: Since `if..then..else` is an expression, the `then` and `else` branches need to have the same type. An `else` can only be skipped if the `then` clause evaluates to `unit`.

Comment: Yes. The fact they need to be the same type applies also for `? :` in C#

Comment: @Enigmativity actually it belongs to both of them.  An if expression can have zero or more elif branches, so `if a then x elif b then y else z` is a single `if` expression.  On the other hand, `if a then x else if b then y else c` is one `if` expression where the `then` branch is itself a second `if` expression.  Compare this to `if a then if b then x else y else z`, which does not compile.  For the `then` branch to contain an `if` expression, the `if` expression needs to be in parentheses: `if a then (if b then x else y) else z`.  This is in contrast to the C# conditional operator.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to save the typing you can define your own

```
let (?=) (q: bool) (yes: 'a, no: 'a) = if q then yes else no
```

Note that you can't use : in operators so ?= is the nearest you can get.

Usage: maybe ?= ("true", "false")

Comment: you can get rid of all those type annotations

Comment: Without the annotations: let (?=) (q) (yes, no) = if q then yes else no

Comment: Careful: this will eagerly evaluate both the true and false side regardless of condition! That is, `if true then printf "a" else printf "b"` will only print `a`, but `true ?= (printf "a", printf "b")` will print `ab`!

Answer (score 6):

You can also implement this using pattern matching with function using guards:

```
    let y = Seq.groupBy  (function |x when x < p -> -1
                                   |x when x = p -> 0
                                   |_ -> 1)
```

Pattern matches may seem longer ternary operator but they are much easier to read when logic gets more complex.

Answer (score 4):

For more examples of C# expressions and statements in F# you can refer to [this](https://lorgonblog.wordpress.com/2008/11/28/what-does-this-c-code-look-like-in-f-part-one-expressions-and-statements/) page. For example:

**Ternary operator**

> C# has the ternary operator "?:" for conditional expressions:
>
> ```
> condition ? trueVal : falseVal
> ```
>
> F# has the same operator, but its name is if-then-else:
>
> ```
> if condition then trueVal else falseVal
> ```
>
> (Note that "if" is used much less frequently in F# than in C#; in F#, many conditionalexpressions are done via pattern-matching rather than if-then-else.)

**Switch statement**

> C# has a switch statement.  It looks something like this:
>
> ```
> switch (x) 
> { 
>     case 1: 
>         SomeCode(); 
>         break; 
>     default: 
>         SomeCode(); 
>         break; 
> }
> ```
>
> In F#, this is just one of many things that pattern matching expresses more succinctly:
>
> ```
>     match x with 
>      | 1 -> SomeCode() 
>      | _ -> SomeCode()  // _ is a ‘catch all’ default
> ```